# How to get a ReadOnlySpan<byte> from a readonly struct?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The following code causes the compiler to throw error CS1605 ("Cannot pass 'var' as a ref or out argument because it is read-only") in the first line of the property getter.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly int Field1;
    public readonly int Field2;

    public MyStruct(int field1, int field2) => (Field1, Field2) = (field1, field2);

    public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Span
    {
        get
        {
            // This code only works when MyStruct is not read only
            ReadOnlySpan<MyStruct> temp = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref this, 1);
            return MemoryMarshal.Cast<MyStruct, byte>(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the `readonly` from the `public readonly struct MyStruct` line makes the code work, but for performance reasons, I would really like the struct to be `readonly`. It makes the code so much more cleaner than having to pass the struct as `ref` all the time.

Is there a way to get a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` from a readonly struct?

**Edit:** ... without creating an implicit or explicit copy of the structure?

Comment: I think you mean "ref struct" (which goes on the stack). I don't think a "readonly struct" will give you any performance improvement.

Comment: I'm assuming the struct is just an example for illustration, but in general, you do not want to go out of your way to prevent copying of an 8-byte struct, because a pointer is just as large (on a 64-bit system), and skipping out on the indirection may well produce better code. The big win from `Span` and co is avoiding heap allocation and the copying of large data structures, not so much avoiding copying of small ones (there are better techniques for that, like packing lots of them into arrays). Certainly they never make code "clean" in any case -- use them where profiling shows it matters.

Comment: Thank you Mario Vernari and Jeroen Mostert. The actual struct is much larger. I'm having millions of "instances" of this struct in a memory mapped file which I need to access as fast as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this works:

```
// The following code will work from C# 7.3 and up, no unsafe keyword required
Span<MyStruct> span = stackalloc MyStruct[1];
span[0] = new MyStruct(3, 4);
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<MyStruct, byte>(span);
```

If we wanted to expose it as a property, we could try the following:

```
// Will not work at runtime
public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Span
{
    get
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (MyStruct* ptr = &this)
            {
                return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(ptr, sizeof(MyStruct)); // If on the heap, we're doomed as returning will unpin the memory.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And marking the struct as a `readonly ref struct`, this guards us again the struct ever being on the heap. This compiles, but doesn't run as you get a `AccessViolationException` at runtime. I will do some more digging to see if it's possible, it should be logically safe to do, but may not be possible today.

Another compromise solution is to keep it as a `readonly struct` (not `ref struct`) and add this static method:

```
public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<byte> GetSpan(ref MyStruct myStruct)
{
    return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref myStruct), sizeof(MyStruct));
}
```

Then from calling code:

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct(1, 2);
var span = MyStruct.GetSpan(ref myStruct);
```

We can improve the usage of this by moving it out into a ref extensions methods (A C# 7.2 feature):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myStruct = new MyStruct(1, 2);
        var span = myStruct.GetSpan();
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly int Field1;
    public readonly int Field2;

    public MyStruct(int field1, int field2) => (Field1, Field2) = (field1, field2);
}

public static class MyStructExtensions
{
    public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<byte> GetSpan(ref this MyStruct myStruct)
    {
        return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref myStruct), sizeof(MyStruct));
    }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed create a ReadOnlyStruct<byte>, but unfortunately this is not very helpful here, because it creates a copy of the structure, which I want to avoid with the readonly struct. I need the ReadOnlyStruct<byte> to be a view directly on the structure's underlying memory.

Comment: It will be very unsafe to do that, as you don't know where the struct lives (stack vs heap), if you made it a `ref struct`, you could guarantee it's stack only, and would be safe to do without assuming you have been pinned by some unsafe code upfront.

Comment: Updated, I'll keep investigating.

Comment: @StefanSchultze where do you think the copy is happening, I've looked at `Memory.Cast<>` and it looks like there is no copying there?

Comment: Not in the Memory.Cast<>, but when setting the first element of the stackalloc array.

The Span getter in my question's example code works without the "unsafe" keyword, so I assumed that it's safe, i.e. that the ReadOnlySpan<byte> never exceeds the lifetime of the struct. So I assumed that I could do the same with the readonly struct, because ReadOnlySpan<byte> wouldn't allow modification of the underlying memory.

Comment: `stackalloc` is now no longer unsafe since C# 7.3, cause you can use it to initialize a `Span`. My first example creates it once on that stack and gives you a `Span` (you can cast to `ReadOnlySpan` if you want) that is not copied.

The thing with a `readonly struct` (not a `readonly ref struct`) is you could be on the heap, the compiler is trying to guard you from this, so you'd need to avoid those checks and as far as I can tell, it's pretty hard to do (which I guess is good).

Comment: I've offered another option

Comment: One last update, I'll stop now. I think this is as close as it gets without some very unsafe code.

Comment: Thank you! I have the same impression - that your third solution is as close as it can get with what C# / .NET Core is offering today.

Comment: Happy to help, this github issue might change things in future: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1792

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a generic solution here, based on the previous answers:

```
public class StructExtensions
{
    public static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<byte> AsSpan<T>(ref T myStruct) where T : struct
    {
        return MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref myStruct, 1));
    }
}
```

You do use it like:

```
var p = StructExtensions.AsSpan<MyStruct>(ref this /* or whatever your variable is */);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code below is unsafe.**

See Stuart comment:

> It will be very unsafe to do that, as you don't know where the struct
>   lives (stack vs heap), if you made it a ref struct, you could
>   guarantee it's stack only, and would be safe to do without assuming
>   you have been pinned by some unsafe code upfront.

`MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan` method [has a warning too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createreadonlyspan?view=netcore-3.0#remarks).

**And now the code**

You can achieve it in two steps.

- Put your struct in a `span<T>` where `T` is the type of your struct.
- Cast the `span<T>` to a `span<byte>`

  ```
  var s = new MutableStruct();
  var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref s, 1);
  var byteSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<MutableStruct, byte>(span);

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", byteSpan.ToArray().Select(v => $"{v:X2}"))); // 00000000

  s.SetX(42);

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", byteSpan.ToArray().Select(v => $"{v:X2}"))); // 2A0000000

  Console.ReadKey();

  // here the used struct
  struct MutableStruct
  {
      private int _x;
      public int X => _x;
      public void SetX(int value) => _x = value;
  }
  ```

You can test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIrYwF)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into source code of [MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Runtime/InteropServices/MemoryMarshal.cs#L235), you can see, that it just creates a new instance of *ReadOnlySpan* by passing *reference* and *length* parameters.

Simple solution would be to create ReadOnlySpan instance yourself by passing array:

```
ReadOnlySpan<MyStruct> temp = new ReadOnlySpan<MyStruct>(new MyStruct[] { this });
```

This will use different [ctor](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/ReadOnlySpan.cs#L44), but implementation is similar and you will get the same result.

**Edit:**

Or using unsafe:

```
public ReadOnlySpan<byte> Span
{
    get
    {
        unsafe
        {

            return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref this), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a heap allocated array though

Comment: You update is a less correct version of my 3rd suggestion , you want the legth to by the size of `MyStruct` in bytes.

Comment: Actually, no it's not. Length is the number of items ReadOnlySpan will contain. Please read the source code.

Comment: My apologies 

Comment: But the type for the ReadOnlySpan is `byte`, so it would be the byte size of `MyStruct`.